# WP_POSTS shows "guid"-links with http://localhost/

Tags: wordpress

I've run the google-pagespeed-insight tool, on which one link has been marked as not being https.
Further investigations lead to a lot of links in wp_posts having http://localhost/(...) as links.

It may be due to me moving of the site from a localhost installation to the live webspace.

So I'm wondering, if i could delete those links, as they won't really point anywhere.
Is there anything else i'd have to check, like other tables?

Thanks folks!

Investigated links via wp_posts and found lots of localhost ones.

Comment: If the URL's aren't being used you are free to delete them, if they are redirecting to localhost instead of your own domain you can choose between replacing them using a SQL query or a WP plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL's are not being triggered on the pages then you are free to delete them, however this could result in unwanted errors. Therefor I suggest you replace all old `localhost` URL's inside of your database with your new URL.

You can achieve this using the following SQL query.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com'); UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
```

Or you can use a WordPress plugin, when I worked with WordPress we mostly used [wp-all-import](https://www.wpallimport.com/). Make sure that after you imported a website using any migration plugin you save the permalinks in the settings tab in wp-admin.

Comment: No wp_posts is further in the SQL query, WordPress saves the perma links on loads of different places. This Query will look for your old URL and if it finds it anywhere it will replace it with your new URL

Answer (score 0):

Posts and pages with links to other posts and pages need to be updated when migrating WordPress sites from one origin domain (like http://localhost) to another (like https://example.com). Hyperlinks inside posts and pages need changing. Therefore, migration is a screaming pain in the xxx neck to do correctly unless you use a migration plugin to do the hard work for you. Then it's simple.

I use Duplicator, but there are several other good choices in the plugin repo.

If you have the choice of repeating your migration using a plugin, that is a good way to handle this.